# Xamarin code behaves differently on different android versions

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a pretty basic login page and it's code behind `LoginPage.xaml.cs` file is as follows:

```
   Client clientLogin;
   bool isLegal = false;


   public LoginPage ()
   {
        InitializeComponent ();
   }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Authenticate);
        actInd.IsRunning = true;
        thread.Name = "Authentication";
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Authenticate()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => LoginButton.IsEnabled = false);

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username_Entry.Text) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password_Entry.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                clientLogin = Login(Username_Entry.Text, Password_Entry.Text);

                if (isLegal)
                {
                    actInd.IsRunning = false;
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new MenuPage()) , true);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    actInd.IsRunning = false;
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => LoginButton.IsEnabled = true);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await DisplayAlert("Uyarı", "Hatalı giriş.\nGirilen şifre veya kullanıcı adı hatalı.", "Tamam"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                actInd.IsRunning = false;
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => LoginButton.IsEnabled = true);
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await DisplayAlert("Uyarı", "Giriş yapılmaya çalışılırken hata oluştu.", "Tamam"));
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            actInd.IsRunning = false;
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => LoginButton.IsEnabled = true);
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await DisplayAlert("Uyarı", "Hatalı giriş.\nBoş kullanıcı adı veya şifre.", "Tamam"));
        }
    }
```

I have two emulators on my pc , they are the same Nexus5X model and they have the same hardware specs.
The only difference is that one has android 6.0 - API 23 as it's OS and the other has android 9.0 - API 29.
When i try to run my program on android 9.0 and try to login it works without any erros however when i try to run it on android 6.0 it produces the following error at the `actInd.IsRunning = false;` line :

> Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
> at

> Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod
> (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
> method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
> <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0    at
> Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod
> (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self,
> Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in
> <286213b9e14c442ba8d8d94cc9dbec8e>:0    at
> Android.Views.View.set_Visibility (Android.Views.ViewStates value)
> [0x00022] in <95d915721ad748108ff096dce8f8f32c>:0    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ActivityIndicatorRenderer.UpdateVisibility
> () [0x00011] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ActivityIndicatorRenderer.cs:73
> at
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ActivityIndicatorRenderer.OnElementPropertyChanged
> (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs
> e) [0x0001f] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ActivityIndicatorRenderer.cs:50
> at (wrapper delegate-invoke)
> .invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs(object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
> at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String
> propertyName) [0x00000] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:229    at
> Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName)
> [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:353    at
> Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual
> (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property,
> Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context,
> System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying,
> Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean
> silent) [0x00114] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:461
> at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore
> (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value,
> Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes,
> Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)
> [0x00173] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:397    at
> Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty
> property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle,
> System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x00042] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:334    at
> Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty
> property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in
> D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:311    at
> Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator.set_IsRunning (System.Boolean value)
> [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ActivityIndicator.cs:29    at
> IncomeMonitoringApp.Views.LoginPage.Authenticate () [0x0008b] in
> D:\Source\App\Solution\File\MyApp\MyApp\Views\LoginPage.xaml.cs:42
> --- End of managed Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException stack trace --- android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.     at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)     at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:942)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5081)  at
> android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:12713)     at
> android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12677)     at
> android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:10634)   at
> android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:7425)   at
> android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.java:1577)

It produces this error only once and when i try to log in again it works without any problems.The problem is from what i understood is that i can't touch my ActivityIndicator from my background thread.My question is: Why ? Why is it ok in android 9.0 but not in 6.0 ? Why does it produce the error only once and work afterwards ? Should i write my according to 6.0 or 9.0 ?

Comment: See following : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jdweng , i have look at the documentation you linked but unfortunately couldn't find anything that could be answer to my question maybe i was unable to see it, if you have any idea as to why it behaves like i've said can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I would try what is in para "Runtime Permissions"

Comment: Yeah also the first thing i checked out but unfortunately it's just news about app permisions.Nothing about UI usage in runtime or anything like that.Still tho thanks.

Comment: The code fails once probably because of the SSL/TLS authentication that occurs.  Not sure why you think problem is a background thread.  I would look at my link at para BoringSSL  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#boringSSL

Comment: I think it's a back ground thread problem because of :                                                 
 1.The error i get : "Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."                                                                       2.When i put a breakpoint at line `if(isLegal)` and step over it the code catches an exception when i try to assign a value to ActivityIndicator's property at line `actInd.IsRunning = false;` until that point no exception is thrown.

Comment: How long does it take for exception to occur?  less than a second, less than 5 seconds, around 30 seconds?  You can try a sniffer to capture when exception occurs.

Comment: Sorry i'm still at junior level i don't get what you mean, i'm already capturing the exception at my `try` `catch` block do i still need another "thing" to debug my application ?

Comment: Just a ruff estimate of time.  You can put a break point just before exception to see if there is a long pause.